# How can i get my community Base URL in apex

Tags: apex, community

I am using  Salesforce Community and I have network Id of the community but I don't know how can I get Base URL of my community. Any one know how can I get my community base URL using its id in apex as a internal user.

Is there any other way in which **salesforce internal user** can get the base URL of all his **community in the apex** also i don't find any object in which Community Base URL is stored. I checked network sObject but it only store community path prefix not the complete URL so how can i get the base URL for my community?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

finally i found the answer i use

> Network.getLoginUrl('Pass Community id here')

in this way i found the login page URL for the community and then break the URL and use as per my Requirement.

Comment: If you do this, you get more than just the base URL, you get `/s/login` at the end of it.  You can do string manipulation, but this approach seems less than reliable, as the login URL could change.  I think Esteban's answer below seems more future-proof.

Comment: @MatthewSouther He has hardcoded the community base URL. It is the same details which I am asking. how you will get the URL? If I store directly in custom setting then I can directly store the complete URL instead of doing all query and checks.

Comment: @MatthewSouther for login its not like we will change it every other day.

Answer (score 2):

this is an approach that you can also take to prepare a base URL when clicking standard or CustomObjects links within a Lightning/VFP (for example).
If you want to load those record Details page dynamically, opening on internal and Community properly, you can use something like this:

```
List<Network> network = [SELECT Name, UrlPathPrefix FROM Network WHERE Name = 'YOUR COMMUNITY NAME'];
String base = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm(); 
if (base.contains('https://yourCommunityDomain.force.com') && !network.isEmpty())
    baseURL = base + '/' + network[0].UrlPathPrefix + '/s/detail';
else 
    baseURL = base;
```

**Notes**:

- I used a List because if you don't reach a Record you get empty list instead of an exception.
- Base URL represents the URL that user is using (it will load for internal and external/Community URLs)
- If it is a Community user access, then I prepare the URL by using the base external Community URL, then the URL you choose for your Community, and then the /s/detail in order to be able to open record Details by ID

Hope it helps, happy code!

Comment: I need the community URL here and you are hardcoding that value. I don' t  think it will solve the issue.

Comment: In fact, it solves the issue, is already working here ;) If you don't want to put the CommunityName in the code directly, you can use Custom Settings too :) The good part of this approach is that you can run internal / external URL accordingly. The code can be evolved if you want. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I did this to get the relative URL, whether internal network or an external site:

```
Id currentNetworkId = Network.getNetworkId();
Network n;
if(currentNetworkId != null) {
    n = [SELECT Id, Name, UrlPathPrefix FROM Network WHERE Id = :currentNetworkId];
}
String relativeUrlBase = '/' + (currentNetworkId != null) ? n.UrlPathPrefix : '';
```

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

On a Visualforce page controller/extension, you can always grab the base URL using the URL class methods in apex:

```
URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()
```

[URL Class documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_url.htm)